# install php7.0 pthreads using package manager

Tags: linux, macos, php, ubuntu-14.04, macports

I do web development.  For development I use mac, installing PHP7.0/Mysql5.6 using macports. On production I use Ubuntu, installing PHP7.0 using apt-get via a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

I have looked at the documentation, for [installing pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php) but all of the resources talk about compiling PHP from source.  I really don't want to go down that route, because (1) it sux, and (2) updates are a hassle.

**How can I install pthreads in such a way that updates are handled with a package manager/automatically, like other extensions are?**